# react-native-video onLoad onProgress not working IOS

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-ios

I have used react-native video for playing audio files, it is working fine on android , but on ios it is not able to fire onLoad and onProgress functions which I am using to get duration and progress. Below is my code.

```
<Video source={{ uri: songPlaying.url }}
          ref="audio"
          volume={this.state.muted ? 0 : 1.0}
          muted={false}
          paused={!this.state.playing}
          onLoad={this.onLoad.bind(this)}                                                   
          onProgress={this.setTime.bind(this)}
          onEnd={this.onEnd.bind(this)}
          resizeMode="cover"
          repeat={false} />    

 onLoad(params) {
    this.setState({ songDuration: params.duration });
  }

//called in onProgress to set time.

 setTime(params) {
    if (!this.state.sliding) {
      this.setState({ currentTime: params.currentTime });
    }
  }
```

Comment: Try to check whether the video is played or not? Try using onError function 1st!

Comment: No error in playing. I checked using onError

Comment: Is the video Playing? Your code looks fine.

Comment: I am playing audio using this library, it is working fine only the event functions are not getting fired

Comment: If you got the solution pls post it or else if you want you can use this component https://github.com/zmxv/react-native-sound

Answer (score 0):

i am using `react-native-video-player` and i was facing this onLoad issue on IOS. So as a work around i set loading to true in `onLoadStart` event and i set loading to false in `onVideoBuffer` as well as in `onLoad` and `onVideoLoad`. This is working fine on both IOS and Android for me.
here is the sample code

```
<VideoPlayer 
      onVideoBuffer={() => setisLoading(false)}
      onLoadStart={() => setisLoading(true)}
      onVideoLoad={() => setisLoading(false)}
      onLoad={() => setisLoading(false)}
      thumbnail={{ uri: item?.thumbnailUrl }}
      controls={false}

      paused={!autoplay || pause}
      video={{
        uri: item?.videoUrl,
      }}
/>
```